# mutt: finding mailboxes with status O (old) unread messages

Tags: imap, mutt, dovecot

Setup: I have a mailserver with mutt installed. The server also has the dovecot IMAP server installed. I read mail both on the server using mutt, and using IMAP clients (eg on my phone). Mail is stored in Maildir folders.

Folder and mutt configuration: I use procmail to deliver incoming mail to various folders. My mutt configuration uses the `mailboxes` command to check the folders for new mail.

Problem: when my IMAP clients sync, dovecot changes the messages to a status that mutt interprets as the `O` (Old) status, rather than the `N` (New) status (see [Read and unread in mutt](https://superuser.com/questions/730010/read-and-unread-in-mutt)), and the `mailboxes` command does not regard folders which have only `O` messages in them as containing unread mail. But I would like it to continue to list these folders: the mere fact of an IMAP client syncing with the server doesn't mean that I no longer want to be able to read that same email on the server, or even that I've seen it on the server.

Is there a way to either have mutt regard folders containing `O` messages as having new mail for the purposes of the `mailbox` functionality or having dovecot not change the status of mails from `N` to `O` when it syncs them with an IMAP client?

Comment: I think this is a Dovecot issue more than a Mutt issue. Do you have administrative (root) access to the server?

Comment: I do have root access.

Answer (score 0):

If you read mail directly from the maildirs, you need to set

```
set maildir_check_cur
```

as dovecot moves mail from `new/` to `cur/`.

(Personally, I use IMAP for mutt too, because that way I can use the same configuration on multiple hosts, and I don't even have mutt running on the host storing the mails anymore.)