# mutt loses 'new' flag on unread emails when changing mailbox

Tags: mutt, offlineimap

I have an anoying misconfiguration in my mail setup and I can't tell where it comes from.

I configured my mutt client to retreive email from Offlineimap with folder-hook to handle multiple accounts. This works well but when I mark a message as `new` it doesn't keep the new flag when I change mailbox.

I'm not using mutt for long so I'm a little bit confused about where this problem could come from. Here is some configuration that I think is relevant :

> ~/.muttrc

```
set folder = ~/.mail
set spoolfile = "+Gmail/INBOX"
source ~/.mutt/accounts/gmail
folder-hook Gmail/* source ~/.mutt/accounts/gmail
folder-hook Plup/* source ~/.mutt/accounts/plup
mailboxes +Gmail/INBOX +Plup/INBOX
[...]
```

> ~/.mutt/accounts/gmail

```
set sendmail = "/usr/bin/msmtp -a gmail"
set from = "me@gmail.com"
set realname = Me
set mbox = "+Gmail/archive"
set postponed = "+Gmail/drafts"
```

> ~/.offlineimaprc

```
[Account Gmail]
localrepository = Gmail-Local
remoterepository = Gmail-Remote
[Repository Gmail-Local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/.mail/Gmail
[Repository Gmail-Remote]
type = Gmail
remoteuser = me@gmail.com
remotepass = secret
realdelete = yes 
maxconnections = 3 
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Any help or debugging ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It actually does the same when I open and close a mailbox. Maybe it has nothing to see with the multiple account but just something wrong in offlineimap and mutt config.

Comment: Could it come from the way I refresh offlineimap, using a full refresh in cron job every 10 minutes.

Comment: Confirmed: Mutt deletes New flags when you close any mailbox. Extremely annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Mutt marks all new mail as Old when closing a mailbox by default, even if unread. Marking when read is another flag. The problem is Mutt only highlights New mail by default, so it's a totally broken idea.

To override the default insane behaviour, add this to you `.muttrc`:

```
mark_old = no
```

Comment: I discussed this in a bit more detail in an answer to the following question: https://superuser.com/questions/730010/read-and-unread-in-mutt